Connecting thermal Pad to the negative supply voltage
I want to use OPA856 and there is a thermal pad. In the datasheet it is mentioned that it should be connected to V-. In my configuration it is V- is -5v, but there is a very small copper region for -5v. I expected this thermal pad should be connected to GND?! is not it?


specifically not a 741. So, don't use that tag.

Op-amps don't naturally have a ground pin because ground is usually just a somewhat stable voltage that sits roughly half way between the V- and V+ supplies. Think also of an op-amp with a single rail power supply; we could make a potential divider between V+ and V- and call the mid-point ground or, we could call the most negative supply (V-) ground. It's arbitrary.
The thermal pad on your device is connected to the negative power pin. If you are using a split rail supply with the mid-point named ground then, the thermal pad cannot connect to ground. It's really all about how we name things.
